# Wait and check a response of web service using uiatomator in android to go forward

Tags: android, automation

I have a login page in my application and after log-in there is a profile page with some set of fields. Now I want to make a test case to log-in in the application and fill the profile details and tap on save using uiautomator.

I am using a web-service for log-in and getting a response and based on the response application is navigating to the profile page or showing the authentication error. As i am newbie for uiautomator I am not getting how to wait till the service responses comes and check the expected response in the service using uioautomator.

Is it possible to do or not what will be the alternative to achieve the same ?